# Failed to get report for ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-maven-plugin: Unable to load the mojo 'report'

Tags: maven, testng, allure, yandex

Could someone help me. I try to start project https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-testng-example. I executed command mvn clean, mvn test and after than "mvn site" and get error:

```
Please refer to D:\temp\allure-testng-example\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) @ allure-testng-example ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-maven-plugin:2.2
сен 07, 2016 5:05:11 PM org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.Logs$JULSink warn
WARNING: Error injecting: ru.yandex.qatools.allure.report.AllureReportMojo
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) No implementation for org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem was bound.
  while locating ru.yandex.qatools.allure.report.AllureReportMojo

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1000)
    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:84)
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Allure Commandline](https://allurereport.org/docs/gettingstarted-installation/) to generate and open report

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Thanks to https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/issues/577  the propblem was in IntelliJ IDEA that use bundled maven as default.

For correct work you should use latest maven version.